# How to exclude substring "TEMP" but include string "TEMPLATE" in regular expression in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-like

How to exclude substring "TEMP" but include string "TEMPLATE" in regular expression in plsql.

I am trying to use condition like below but all are getting excluded

code:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
from all_tables
where not regexp_like( table_name, '_(TEMP)')
  and     regexp_like( table_name, 'TEMPLATE');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need regular expressions? How about

```
select table_name
  from all_tables
  where instr(table_name, 'TEMPLATE') > 0
```

If it isn't that simple (according to your comment), then consider something like this:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     all_tables (table_name)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'MY_TEMPLATE' FROM DUAL   -- OK
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'EXC_ABC' FROM DUAL       -- not OK, contains _ABC
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 'EMP' FROM DUAL           -- OK
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 'DEPT' FROM DUAL          -- OK
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT 'YOUR_TEMPXX2' FROM DUAL) -- not OK, contains _TEMP
 13  SELECT *
 14    FROM all_tables
 15   WHERE    NOT REGEXP_LIKE (table_name, '_(TEMP|ABC|DEF|XYZ)|[[:digit]]')
 16         OR REGEXP_LIKE (table_name, 'TEMPLATE');

TABLE_NAME
------------
MY_TEMPLATE
EMP
DEPT

SQL>
```

Comment: I need to select  tables from all_tables excluding several strings and including several strings. hence the need. e.g. where not regexp_like( table_name, '_(TEMP|ABC|DEF|XYZ)|[[:digit]]'))
  and     regexp_like( table_name, 'TEMPLATE');

Answer (score 0):

You can use combined logic with `AND` with `OR` containing exception for the word `TEMPLATE` such as

```
 WHERE ( table_name NOT LIKE '%TEMP%' AND table_name NOT LIKE '%TEMPLATE%' )
    OR   table_name LIKE '%TEMPLATE%'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=077f31d4d098246d2a7663bfc7d5a92e)</kbd>